# Complex assertion of table in Capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have a table in my app.

[image]

Using Capybara and Cucumber, how do I assert that values 4.5 and 1.1 happen only in the Mike's row?
Is such assertion possible in Capybara?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and easy:

```
def td_text(n)
  find(:xpath, "./td[#{n}]").text
end

h = {2 => 4.5, 3 => 1.1}

all('table tr').each do |row|
  within row do
    if td_text(1) == 'Mike'
      h.each { |i, value| td_text(i).should == value.to_s }
    else
      h.each { |i, value| td_text(i).should_not == value.to_s }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's [full script](https://gist.github.com/4637735) that you can use for testing

**Update:** I thought about it more. The code above will be very slow as every invocation of `find` and `text` in `td_text` will make new query to browser.

The only way to mitigate it that I see is to use JS and Nokogiri:

```
source = page.evaluate_script("document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML")

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(source)

def td_text(row, n)
  row.xpath("./td[#{n}]").text
end

h = {2 => 4.5, 3 => 1.1}

doc.css('tr').each do |row|
  if td_text(row, 1) == 'Mike'
    h.each { |i, value| td_text(row, i).should == value.to_s }
  else
    h.each { |i, value| td_text(row, i).should_not == value.to_s }
  end
end
```

The first variant of code runs about 200 milliseconds at my machine though the second one - 8 milliseconds. Good optimization!

Comment: Seriously great optimization! Thank you Andrey!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [within](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#within-instance_method) to scope where you are searching for a specific value:

For example, to assert that value 4.5 happens in the second column of  Mike's row, try the following:

```
within("table tr:nth-child(2)") do
  find("td:nth-child(2)").text.should == 4.5
end
```

You can wrap these in helper methods for ease of use if you would like:

```
def within_row(num, &block)
  within("table tr:nth-child(#{num})", &block)
end

def column_text(num)
  find("td:nth-child(#{num})").text
end
```

Now you could make the same assertion about Mike's row by doing the following:

```
within_row(2) do
  column_text(2).should == 4.1
end
```

Hopefully you will find one of these techniques useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, @John Dyer! Is there an easy way to find the row number where Mike is? Say, it could be in row 2 or 3.

Comment: I am not certain. I haven't seen or used capybara that way before and there doesn't appear to be an obvious way to do that. While it is most likely possibly, it might take some digging to figure out.